# Wireless Router will not allow connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am working with a RangeMax(TM) Wireless Router WPN824 v2, and it will not allow a wireless connection nor a wired connection.

I am at an actual lost, with no way into the router I cannot test settings.  I have unplugged it, left it off for a 32 hours, and reset it with no luck.

Any ideas?  Could the router just be done-zo?

Comment: Now I have finally got it to reset, but a new problem develops.  The wireless does not work (I assume its off by default), but upon connecting to the router it claims (in a browser) that the device is controlled by 192.168.1.2.  There is no device with this IP address on the network.  There is no access to the web control panel located on the router.

Comment: What is the IP address your computer gets from the router?

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried resetting the router without any success could be a hardware problem with the device. Have you also checked the cable that runs from your modem to your router and confirmed that the cable is good?

Comment: +1. Hard reset router (with reset switch) then log in again. If it still says someone is managing it, RMA it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the ip range 192.168.1.x ? The default IP of the router is 192.168.1.1 so, the first time, you must have an ip in this range to set up it.

The message that say that the device is controlled by is 192.168.1.2 is odd, may be it has already been hacked? What's the status of the wireless led?

Comment: The wireless LED doesn't even turn on.  The only thing that shows up is a check mark to the far left of the device.  I am in the 1.x subnet so the device recognized my presence, but gives me the 192.168.1.2 controller error.

Comment: I don't see what it could be... Double check: Unplug everything except you, reboot (unplug / wait a little / plug the power cable) or reset it (insert  something in the little hole in the back for 15 seconds, when it's powered on). And try again

Answer (score 0):

Do network cables connected to it show as "Connected"?

The only way I can think of to check if it's completely f**ked is to plug the WAN port into a computer, start [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on that NIC, and power it up. If it's working, you should see some DHCP activity as it tries to retrieve an IP from your ISP.

If it doesn't do that, it's probably a hardware failure.